# Rule for inheritance — return type of overriding method can be child class of return type declared in overridden method

Tags: java, inheritance

I was going through inheritance rules. I came across below rule

**return type of overriding method can be child class of return type declared in overridden method.**

I don't understand the purpose behind it.
If any one can explain it.

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to use more specific return type when you're using specific subclass. A common example would be to use more specific return type when overriding `clone()` method. It's declared like

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

So it returns `Object`. But in your particular class (say, `MyObject`) you can redefine clone like this:

```
public MyObject clone() {
    try {
        return (MyObject)super.clone();
    }
    catch(CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
        throw new InternalError();
    }
}
```

This way users of your `MyObject` class can call the `clone()` method and get the `MyObject` result without additional casting. It's quite convenient.

Comment: Good example. How are you able to downcast `super.clone()` to type `MyObject` when `super.clone()` returns an `Object` type? In other words, how are you able to downcast an Object to type MyObject?

Comment: @rb612 - You can always do *explicit typecast* / *downcast* . Your code will compile. But if the types are *incompatible*, then in *run-time*, you will get `ClassCastException`

Comment: As [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--) says, `super.clone()` call creates a new instance of the current object whatever it is. It's native JVM code and JVM knows how to do this. Thus you can safely cast it to the current class.

Comment: Ahhh, I was not aware `super.clone()` returns a new clone of the current class. Why do we invoke the clone method on super and not `this.clone()`?

Comment: Invoking `this.clone()` you will call the same method you are in. That's infinite recursion. You will got `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's what I think can happen.

Let's say you have the following:

```
public class Animal {
...
   public Animal anotherAnimal() {
      return new Animal();
   }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
...
   public Dog anotherAnimal() {
      return new Dog();
   }
}
```

So what's happening here is we're overriding the superclass method `anotherAnimal`, and the rule is that in the child class (Dog), we are allowed to return a different object than the superclass' method did, but it has to return an object that's a subclass.

In other words, because `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal` we're able to return it in the overridden `Dog` method.

Comment: Also note that *you cannot reduce visibility of the overriden method*. i.e, the *overriden* method of the child can never be *private*

Comment: i am aware of it but logical purpose behind it why it has implemented in such a way